# PHP - add element at the end of an array

Tags: php, arrays

So I'm trying to insert an element(?) at the end of an object(?) in my array.

```
foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
  // pak orginele vraag + titel
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM mdl_evaluation_question WHERE id = ".$key;
  $question = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);

  while($q = $question->fetch_assoc()) {

    // check of vraag van toepassen is voor de docent & bereken gemiddelde
    if ($q['teacher'] == 1) {

      array_push($info,  array('title' => $q['title'],
                            'Gemiddelde' => number_format($result['result']/$result['times'], 1)));

      // check if there is any feedback
      if ($result['feedback'] > 0) {
         // So here I'm trying to add the feedback behind the 'gemiddelde'
         array_push($info, array('feedback' => 'feedbacks.php?course='.$_GET['course'].'&date='.$_GET['date'].'&question='.$key.'">'.$result['feedback'].' feedback(s) gegeven'));
      }
    }
  }
}
echo json_encode($info);
```

So what I get is :

```
[{"title":"Inschrijven voor de cursus","Gemiddelde":"7.4"}]
```

But what I'm trying is, if there is any feedback, add feedback behind 'gemiddelde' within the brackets. For example:

```
[{"title":"Inschrijven voor de cursus","Gemiddelde":"7.4", "feedback": "something"}]
```

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and this should be addressed ASAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, if i got the question.
If feedback is present, you want to add to the current object, right?

```
    foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
        // pak orginele vraag + titel
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM mdl_evaluation_question WHERE id = ".$key;
        $question = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);

        while($q = $question->fetch_assoc()) {
            if ($q['teacher'] == 1) {
                // Initiliaze object
                $curArray = array(
                    'title' => $q['title'],
                    'Gemiddelde' => number_format($result['result']/$result['times'], 1)
                );

                // check if there is any feedback
                if ($result['feedback'] > 0) {
                    // Add feedback to current object
                    $curArray['feedback'] = 'feedbacks.php?course='.$_GET['course'].'&date='.$_GET['date'].'&question='.$key.'">'.$result['feedback'].' feedback(s) gegeven';                   
                }

                // Add the object to the array
                array_push($info, $curArray);
            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($info);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the feedback information using [] after the name of the array.

```
 // check if there is any feedback
      if ($result['feedback'] > 0) {
         $info[] = $result['feedback'];
      }
```

Comment: should be `$info['feedback'] = $result['feedback']` - OP desired output has key of feedback (nitpicking I know but ... haha)

Comment: Ha, yep, that could be true but it looks like the original question was changed.